# Where are PDFs stored from ddjvu or djvu2pdf?

Tags: pdf, djvu

I cannot locate the directory after making the conversion from djvu to pdf when using either `ddjvu` or djvu2pdf`. Unless  specify a specific path, i.e.

```
ddjvu -format=pdf "/Users/x/Downloads/Ramanujan/Continued Fractions/Continued fractions (Carl D. Olds, A. Rockett, P. Szusze) (Z-Library).djvu" /Users/x/Downloads/Continued_Fractions.pdf
```

Then its stored in my Downloads, but where does it naturally store the pdfs?